# What happend if I update my website?

Tags: updates

I want to update my website (www.kerstlichtjestocht-loosdrecht.nl). But what happend if I do that? I want to use some plugins but they don't do it with my version of Wordpress. Can you see or give me some advice what happend if I update this version to the newest version?

I got version WordPress 3.7.27.

I hope to hear from you soon!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a choice in Admin, Updates to update to the latest version. Use that, as it is 'smart' enough to figure out all the updates needed to the database structures, etc.

After updating, use the Admin, Update screen to ensure that all plugins and themes are updated. Do the 'Check Again' until everything is current.

Of course, backup your database first before all of that, just in case something goes wrong.